# Why am I getting zero each time during comparison of linear and binary searching?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, time.h

I want to find the **time taken** to find an element in an array by **linear and binary searching**. I have passed variable **n** which takes an integer and it continuously decreases it's value by 1 upto 0. I want to get the total time table chart for comparing linear & binary searching i.e. from the array size of 1 to any large number. But I am getting 0.000000 time for each of these case.

My goal is to plot time elapsed by both of these searching when (x) i.e. the input size is 0 to any large number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

long int lin_search(long int [], long int, long int );
long int bin_Search(long int [], long int, long int, long int);
void merge(long int [], long int, long int, long int );
void mergeSort(long int [], long int, long int);

long int main()
{
    long int n, *arr, x;
    clock_t start, end;
    FILE *fp;
    double lin_time , bin_time ;

    //Destination file:  "search_comp.txt"
    fp = fopen("search_comp.txt", "a");

    printf("\nEnter total no of inputs:\t");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    printf("\n::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n");
    while (n--)
    {
        arr = (long int *)malloc(n * sizeof(long int));
        for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % n;
        }

        mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
        x = rand() % n;
        //Linear search time..
        start = clock();
        long int res1 = lin_search(arr, n, x);
        end = clock();
        lin_time = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        //Binary search time ...
        start = clock();
        long int res2 = bin_Search(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
        end = clock();
        bin_time = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        //File creation data taking input........
        fprintf(fp, "%ld;%lf;%lf;%ld;%ld\n", n, lin_time, bin_time, res1, res2);
        free(arr);
    }

    printf("\nTask Completed!\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

long int lin_search(long int arr[],long int n,long int x)
{
    long int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == x)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

long int bin_Search(long int arr[],long int l,long int r,long int x)
{
    while (l <= r)
    {
        long int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        if (arr[m] == x)
            return m;

        if (arr[m] < x)
            l = m + 1;

        else
            r = m - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void merge(long int arr[],long int l,long int m,long int r)
{
    long int i, j, k;
    long int n1 = m - l + 1;
    long int n2 = r - m;

    long int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];


    i = 0; 
    j = 0; 
    k = l; 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(long int arr[],long int l,long int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {

        long int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

[image: Error message from the system for large value of n]

Moreover the program works fine if I omit the while loop (upto 100,000) i.e.

```
while(n--)
{
    :::::
    :::::
    :::::
}
printf("\nTask Completed!\n");
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

And for higher values of **n** the program is not showing my **Task Completed!** message.

Comment: Forget about trying to time anything. Seems like the basic program is not even working as it seems to be crashing somewhere. Reduce the code and debug it in smaller pieces. For example, remove the sort and test just the merge first. If that works fine then add in the linear sort and test that. And so on.

Comment: Or use `valgrind`

Comment: Oops, Windows. . .

Comment: Note: `long int main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Tip: `long` is a shorter way than `long int` to mean `signed long int`.

Comment: The crash is due to a divide by zero error.  `while(n--)` should be `for (; n; --n)`

Comment: On my relatively slow machine, the times for n=100,000 are `0.000093` and `0.000004`. That you are getting zero is therefore unsurprising.

Comment: `main` must return `int` not `long int`.

Comment: Yes...I take note of that...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid division or mod by 0

```
//while (n--) {
for ( ; n; n--)  {
  ...
  x = rand() % n;
```